# How can I make a zero padding ag-grid table?

Tags: ag-grid

I have read the ag-grid documentation on themes but have not been able to create a truly zero padding table. I tried another posters stackblitz that lets me change the theme variables and I can't get it the table to really shrink much. I can set the padding variables to zero and the row height to 12 (or less) but the actual table row doesn't get much smaller, just the text.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-djhzqb?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

Example params

```
$font-size: 11px;
$secondary-font-size: 11px;
$cell-horizontal-padding: 0px;
$cell-vertical-padding: 0px;
$row-height: 10px;
$header-height: 10px;
$virtual-item-height: 10px;
```

Is there some other trick to getting the table row to actually squeeze down to the size of the text?

Edit:

This is an example of how tight I would like the padding:

[image]

Compared to the stock ag-grid which has huge padding everywhere

[image]

Comment: What exacty are you looking for? Do you want a fixed width for all cells?

Comment: @wentjun I am more concerned with the top/bottom padding than the width of the cells.